# Replication with LocalDB feature of MS SQL Express 2012

Tags: replication, localdb

Is it possible to have any replication (via RMO) with 2012 Express LocalDB?

I read that Merge Replication is not possible (disappointed!) but are other replication activities possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sync Framework, it generally Works with any database